# React-Redux app with Node backend shows previous user's info on login

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

I've got an app which requests a bunch of plots from the backend based on the present user's company code. The problem is that when a user logs in, it shows him the previous user's plots. On refresh, the app shows the current user's plots, as it is supposed to.

I'm using JWT stored in local storage for authentication. Looking in local storage, the user's information is properly stored and disposed of on logout.

The API endpoint:

```
if (req.user.companyCode === 'admin') {
    plotStatus = await PlotStatus.find({}).lean();
} else {
    plotStatus = await PlotStatus.find({
        company: req.user.companyCode
    }).lean();
}
if (!plotStatus) {
    throw new Error('Plot Statuses not found');
} else {
    res.send(plotStatus);
}
```

The Redux action:

```
export function fetchPlotStatuses() {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    return function(dispatch) {
        axios
            .get(`${ROOT_URL}/plotstatuses`, {
                headers: { authorization: user.token }
            })
            .then(response => {
                dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_PLOTSTATUSES,
                    payload: response.data
                });
            });
    };
}
```

Comment: If you can see the previous user's info, then you must be reading it from somewhere that is not cleared when the user logs out.

Comment: But I'm seeing it display only after the GET request to the backend turns around.

Comment: Are you testing this on same computer? Could be just some kind of caching issue.

Comment: I'm seeing the issue come up even when the app is deployed to Azure.

Comment: When I clear storage before signing in again, the issue persists.